# Worker cannot connect to docker swarm manager

Tags: docker-swarm

I have setup the docker swarm manager in one machine with IP 192.168.XXX.XXX by using this command :

docker swarm init  --advertise-addr=192.168.XXX.XXX
and I got this message :

```
To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1- 
0jpgak7bm7t4mzluz48gdub06f5036q8yaoo99awkjmlz48vtb- 
1eutz0k1vp37ztmiuxdnglka2 192.168.XXX.XXX:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.
```

In other machine I tried the following command :

```
docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1- 
0jpgak7bm7t4mzluz48gdub06f5036q8yaoo99awkjmlz48vtb- 
1eutz0k1vp37ztmiuxdnglka2 192.168.XXX.XXX:2377
```

and the result was :

```
error response from daemon : rpc error : code = Unavailable desc = all 
SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error 
: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp 192.168.XXX.XXX:2377 : 
connect: connection refused
```

Docker version :

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:47:51 2018
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.0
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       4d60db4
  Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:55:00 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a connection refused error you are running into. Most likely, the other machine cannot connect to the manager as it is not on the same network. Solution: To fix this, the two machines have to be able to talk to each other. If the machines are in a cloud like Azure or AWS create a virtual network and add the two machines to it.

Debugging connection refused error:

To confirm the machines cannot talk to each other, try pinging the manager from the other machine. It will most likely fail in your current setup.

```
$ ping 192.168.XXX.XXX
```

If it succeeds then check if port 2377 is open and listening on the manager. Run below from the other machine:

```
$ nc -vz 192.168.XXX.XXX 2377
```

Another tool that can help in debugging is to run `netstat` on the manager:

```
$ netstat -tuplen
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        51772227   -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25361290   -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::2377                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          1423965    -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::7946                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          1423980    -
```

Verify you see `:::2377` and `:::7946` and that their state is set to `LISTEN` as these ports are required by docker swarm [[1](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/)]